# Show the distance does not exceed $\sqrt{2}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Choose any ten points from the interior of a square with side length $3$. Show that the distance of some pair of these points does not exceed $\sqrt{2}$.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 20):

Hint:  divide the square $3 \times 3$

Comment: +2: awesome hint!

Comment: +3: this is great.